# Scraping multiple URL's in Selenium and writing to JSON

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on a scraper using Selenium.

I have written the script and it is scraping properly, however I am trying to scrape multiple URL's, then write the results to JSON.

The script scrapes, and prints successfully, however I am only getting one result in the JSON - the second URL's detail (I am getting both results when printing).

How do I get both URL's results?

I think I need to add another FOR LOOP for the JSON data, but can't figure out how to add it in!

This is the code I am working with:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import json

def writeToJSONFile(path, fileName, data):
    filePathNameWExt = './' + path + '/' + fileName + '.json'
    with open(filePathNameWExt, 'a') as fp:
        json.dump(data, fp, ensure_ascii=False)

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/Users/path/geckodriver")

urls = ['https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Restaurant_Review-g186338-d8122594-Reviews-Humble_Grape_Battersea-London_England.html','https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Restaurant_Review-g186338-d5561842-Reviews-Gastronhome-London_England.html']

data = {}
for url in urls:

    browser.get(url)
    page = browser.find_element_by_class_name('non_hotels_like')
    title = page.find_element_by_class_name('heading_title').text
    street_address = page.find_element_by_class_name('street-address').text

    print(title)
    print(street_address)


data = {}
data['title'] = title
data['street_address'] = street_address

filename = 'properties'
writeToJSONFile('./', filename, data)

browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to add values with the same keys to dictionary while Python dict can contain unique keys only! So instead of writing second `title` you're just overwriting it. The same with `street_address`

You can try to save data as list of dictionaries:

```
data = []

for url in urls:
    browser.get(url)
    page = browser.find_element_by_class_name('non_hotels_like')
    title = page.find_element_by_class_name('heading_title').text
    street_address = page.find_element_by_class_name('street-address').text

    print(title)
    print(street_address)

    data.append({'title': title, 'street_address': street_address})
```

Comment: That is even cleaner! If I would do it I'll do it your way! yet I tried to use dict as in the question...

Comment: @MosheSlavin , Note that with your solution key-value pairs will look like `{'1title': 'value', '2title': 'value'}`. That might create some difficulties when parsing JSON. Also f-strings are available from Python 3.6, so you might need to add some clarification to your code to not confuse OP which can use earlier Python version...

Answer (score 1):

You are resting the data variable after the loop...

So... what I did is add the index of iteration using enumerate and formated it into the key...

Try this should work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import json

def writeToJSONFile(path, fileName, data):
    filePathNameWExt = './' + path + '/' + fileName + '.json'
    with open(filePathNameWExt, 'a') as fp:
        json.dump(data, fp, ensure_ascii=False)

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/Users/path/geckodriver")

urls = ['https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Restaurant_Review-g186338-d8122594-Reviews-Humble_Grape_Battersea-London_England.html','https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Restaurant_Review-g186338-d5561842-Reviews-Gastronhome-London_England.html']

data = {}
for i, url in enumerate(urls):

    browser.get(url)
    page = browser.find_element_by_class_name('non_hotels_like')
    title = page.find_element_by_class_name('heading_title').text
    street_address = page.find_element_by_class_name('street-address').text
    # this 'f' string formating is suported from Python 3.6+ you can use other format... (for a cleaner job use list see the excpted answer...) 
    data[f'{i}title'] = title
    data[f'{i}street_address'] = street_address

    print(title)
    print(street_address)


filename = 'properties'
writeToJSONFile('./', filename, data)

browser.quit()
```

Hope you find this helpful!

Comment: Still only getting one result! Any ideas why? Thanks!

Comment: @James5949 try now hope this helps you!

Comment: It would probably be better to add the results as a tuple or dictionary to data using the url as a key, as
data[url] = {"title":title, "street address":street_address}

Comment: @ArthurEndlein that is what I did in the beginning but the URL's are very long...

Comment: So maybe using a list instead of a dictionary for data?
data.append({"title":title, "street address":street_address})
You could also add the url to the dict, if needed. That way it would be easier to access data afterwards.

Comment: I agree... see @Anderssons answer... yet I tried to stay as close to the question...